# ODE interval of definition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, probability, statistics

I wish to find the interval of definition of dy/dx= √(1-y^2) for y = sinx. So in other words, I need to find an interval where cosx= √(1-sin^2(x)) =|cosx| or when cosx is non negative. That is [0, π/2], [3 π/2 2 π].. So just checking if this correct and how to express the final answer, ie range when cos x is nonnegative, in a more elegant way instead of as above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question appears to be when is 
$$
\cos x=|\cos x|
$$
which is when $\cos x\geq 0$ as you noted. The answer is in the first and fourth quadrants (for the unit circle). I.e when 
$$
-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}
$$
But this is not all the points we want. Really any point satisfying 
$$
2\pi k-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq x\leq 2\pi k+\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ will do (we're just taking another walk around the unit circle).

If you want a fancier way, you can write the set where $x$ is allowed to live as
$$
\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}[2\pi k-\frac{\pi}{2},2\pi k+\frac{\pi}{2}]
$$
but I think the above is clearer.